# How to format complex section header

Tags: sectioning, formatting, color

I've got several question, all relating to the below image. Within my `.cls` file I am trying to style the section headers like so:

[image: example title]

1. My first question was how do I stop \sections from being numbered.
2. How do I underline my section heading with a dashed line which goes across the whole page
3. How do I prefix and append a character (in this case `'['` and `']'`) to my section headers
4. How do I change the colour of the dashed underline and the prefix and suffix of my sections without affecting the section colour

(sorry if the blue is a little hard to see)

Some of the Answers:

1. By using `\section*{SECTION NAME}` instead of \section{SECTION NAME} the section is not numbered.
2. There is a package called `arydshln` which has a command called `\hdashline` which creates a dashed line under the section. However, has to be explicit, is it possible to add this to the \section definition?

I am unsure how to add the prefix and suffix to the section and to change the colour of the them, along with the underline.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What's not entirely clear is whether you want no section numbering at all, or only for some sections?

Comment: see package `titlesec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a starting point for you with `titlesec`.  I will not comment the code, check the documentation of `titlesec` for a description:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,color}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  [hang]
  {\sffamily\large\bfseries\color{blue}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {[~{\color{magenta}\MakeUppercase{#1}}~]}
  [\vspace{3pt}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{\_}}]

% This is the answer to  how do I stop \sections from being numbered?
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\section{Personal Statement}
\label{sec:personal-statement}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You also might get some letterspacing in title with the `\lsstyle` from `microtype`.